# Custom type for partial word search in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am in a tight schedule for a demo with Elastic Search.

I have setup my database, used JDBC input with Logstash and started indexing database tables. Its all working fine for some extent. But partial word search is not working. A quick search in Elastic documents suggested nGram filters and stemmers. Since I didn't get stemmers I followed the path of ngram filters.

Following is my index mapping,

```js
{
 "settings" : {
 "analysis" : {
  "analyzer" : {
   "translation_index_analyzer" : {
    "type" : "custom",
    "tokenizer" : "standard",
    "filter" : "standard, lowercase, translation"
   },
   "translation_search_analyzer" : {
    "type" : "custom",
    "tokenizer" : "standard",
    "filter" : "standard, lowercase"
   }  
  },
  "filter" : {
   "translation" : {
    "type" : "nGram",
    "min-gram" : 3,
    "max-gram" : 12
   }
  }
     }
 }, 
 "mappings" : {
        "type" : {
  "properties" : {
       "myType" : {
   "type" : "string",
                        "index_analyzer" : "translation_index_analyzer",
                        "search_analyzer" : "translation_search_analyzer"
       } 
  }
        }, 
        "employee" : {
            "properties" : {
                      "birth_date": {
                             "type": "date",
                            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZ"
          },
          "emp_no": {
                   "type": "long",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "first_name": {
            "type": "myType"
          },
          "gender": {
            "type": "string",
              "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "hire_date": { 
                             "type": "date",
                            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZ"
         },
          "last_name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
            }
        }
    }
```

I rather guessed the type mapping as  I need something like that desperately. Not sure whether thats correct.

When I post this I am getting the error

```js
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "analyzer on field [myType] must be set when search_analyzer is set"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [type]: analyzer on field [myType] must be set when search_analyzer is set",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "analyzer on field [myType] must be set when search_analyzer is set"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Any clue where I have got it wrong?

**UPDATE:** My elastic version is 2.2
change from index_analyzer to analyzer gave a different error

```js
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "No handler for type [myType] declared on field [first_name]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [employee]: No handler for type [myType] declared on field [first_name]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "No handler for type [myType] declared on field [first_name]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

**FINAL SOLUTION:** 
Well, my issue was with defining a type. Which I will ignore for the moment but partial search works with following setup

```js
{
"settings" : {
            "analysis" : {
                "analyzer" : {
                    "my_ngram_analyzer" : {
                        "tokenizer" : "my_ngram_tokenizer"
                    }
                },
                "tokenizer" : {
                    "my_ngram_tokenizer" : {
                        "type" : "nGram",
                        "min_gram" : "3",
                        "max_gram" : "12",
                        "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit" ]
                    }
                }
            }
},
 
 "mappings" : {
 
        "employee" : {
            "properties" : {
                      "birth_date": {
                             "type": "date",
                            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZ"
          },
          "emp_no": {
                   "type": "long",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "first_name": {
            "type": "string",
                        "analyzer" : "my_ngram_analyzer",
                        "search_analyzer" : "my_ngram_analyzer"
          },
          "gender": {
            "type": "string",
              "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "hire_date": { 
                             "type": "date",
                            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZ"
          },
          "last_name": {
            "type": "string",
                        "analyzer" : "my_ngram_analyzer",
                        "search_analyzer" : "my_ngram_analyzer"
          }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the elasticsearch version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess, change `index_analyzer` with `analyzer`

- It's depend your elasticsearch version

**EDIT**

I'm not familiar with creating type, but you can init `first_name` with the relevant analyzer:

```
"first_name": {
  "type" : "string",
  "analyzer" : "translation_index_analyzer",
  "search_analyzer" : "translation_search_analyzer"
},
```

Comment: Elastic version is 2.2 the latest.

Comment: Thanks @Roy Shmuli, I tried that too. then it doesn;t give me any errors by partial search doesn't work. Is there a way to see the tokenised output ? At the end I have to index about 150 columns. Thats why I thought of a custom type which makes its clean and easy.

Comment: Maybe this will help you (in the end of the page): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html

Comment: Thanks Roy. I will accept this as the answer because it solved the question I had. My issue was defining a type. I am yet to find an answer for that. But partial searching works now.