# Elastic custom filed types

Tags: elasticsearch

This is related to  [one of my other question in Elastic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35256368/custom-type-for-partial-word-search-in-elastic-search)

I have to index about 150 fields in different tables and I want some of them to be able to be searched partially.

One thing I can do (as in the answer to above question) is set analyzer and search analyzer in all fields I want partially searched.

But I am sure elastic is having a better way of doing it. Can I define my own *field type* like 'string' with analyzers preset and set it as type for fields required to be partially searched?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can define your own type. But you can achieve something using `Dynamic Templates`.

Use `dynamic Templates` like :

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "mappings": {
  "my_type": {
     "dynamic_templates": [
        {
           "analysed_string_template": {
              "match": "*_someText",
              "match_mapping_type": "string",
              "mapping": {
                 "type": "string",
                 "analyzer": "your_analyser"
               }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
     }
```

This will make all your string that ends with `someText` as analysed.You can change the `"match"` field as per your requirement.
Study about `dynamic_templates` [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html)

Hope this helps..

Comment: hmm.. thanks @Richa. I will try that but then I have to format my fields to match the dynamic query.... :(

Comment: Yes ,that you might you have to do. But you can give it a try.